# Mysql select Timestamp compare

Tags: php, mysql

In database column datatype **Item_Expired = timestamp**

Return result 2

```
$querySelectItemsEnd = "SELECT * FROM auction_items WHERE Item_Expired <= NOW() AND Item_Status = 'close'  ";
$stmtSelctItemsEnd = $conn->prepare($querySelectItemsEnd);
$stmtSelctItemsEnd->execute();
$rowCountSelectItemsEnd = $stmtSelctItemsEnd->rowCount();
```

Return result 7

```
   $querySelectItemsEnd = "SELECT * FROM auction_items WHERE Item_Status = 'close'  ";
    $stmtSelctItemsEnd = $conn->prepare($querySelectItemsEnd);
    $stmtSelctItemsEnd->execute();
    $rowCountSelectItemsEnd = $stmtSelctItemsEnd->rowCount();
```

Question : both of code work perfectly but only the result return are different. But the correct result are 7 , because inside my database there are 7 items are expired. Thus, the code 1 it use **Item_Expired <= NOW()** but only return me 2 result, it incorrect for using this?? because i want to check if the Item_Expired are less than current time then display it out.So how can i do it correct??

Comment: What dates are for that 7 results ?

Comment: Try with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` instead of `NOW()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the field is a timestamp field. Try this:

```
$querySelectItemsEnd = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(Item_Expired, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS expired FROM auction_items 
                        WHERE expired <= NOW() AND 
                              Item_Status = 'close'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this,

```
$querySelectItemsEnd = "SELECT * FROM auction_items 
                        WHERE Item_Expired <='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' AND 
                              Item_Status = 'close'  ";
```

Comment: Was gonna say the above with a slight change: (Have added an answer as I cant add code to a comment)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it maybe that the value of `Item_Expired` is in `('d-m-y')` format and `now()` function returns into `('d-m-y h:i:s')`. so try `date('d-m-y')`.